# Images breaking between localhost and Netlify using NetlifyCMS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms, jamstack

OK, I'm pretty new to JAMstack, React, GatsbyJS, NetlifyCMS and Netlify, so do forgive me if this is simple.

I have a site running using React and GatsbyJS, and have NetlifyCMS running too to control the content. For the most part the site is running fine, however I keep running into an issue when it comes to images between the different environments.

When I add an image into the body section of any page through NetlifyCMS, I then pull the repo the image simply doesn't appear and is replaced with the broken image icon. However, it seems to work fine when on Netlify.

Occasionally, it appears, but after a push or a pull or restarting the Gatsby develop server, it just breaks again.

It only seems to happen when adding an image via NetlifyCMS into the body content so it appears in the main content of the markdown file; it is seemingly working fine when in frontmatter.

I've spent many hours on this it seems. I've got the full range of plugins installed, and I can't seem to find anyone else that is facing this issue.

All the other HTML seems to work fine but these images really don't want to.

**gatsby-config.js**

```
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Sheringham Shantymen',
    description: 'The Shantymen travel widely throughout the UK and Ireland supporting Lifeboat Stations in their fundraising efforts and are always considering how they can help in others to raise funds by performing concerts.',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        plugins: [
        "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files",
        "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths",
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
            options: {
              name: 'uploads',
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
            options: {
              // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
              // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
              // base for generating different widths of each image.
              maxWidth: 1600,
            },
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    {
      // keep as first gatsby-source-filesystem plugin for gatsby image support
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/static/img`,
        name: 'uploads',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/img`,
        name: 'images',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/gigs`,
        name: 'gigs',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/discography`,
        name: 'discography',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader',
      options: {
        google: {
          families: ['Source Sans Pro', 'Source Serif Pro']
        }
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: "Sheringham Shantymen",
        short_name: "Shantymen",
        start_url: "/",
        background_color: "#172957",
        theme_color: "#FAC43E",
        // Enables "Add to Homescreen" prompt and disables browser UI (including back button)
        // see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#display
        display: "standalone",
        icon: "src/img/logo-badge.png", // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms',
      options: {
        modulePath: `${__dirname}/src/cms/cms.js`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve:'gatsby-plugin-purgecss', // purges all unused/unreferenced css rules
      options: {
        develop: true,            // Activates purging in npm run develop
        purgeOnly: ['/all.sass'], // applies purging only on the bulma css file
      },
    }, // must be after other CSS plugins
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify', // make sure to keep it last in the array
  ],
}
```

**Content.js component**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const HTMLContent = ({ content, className }) => (
  <div className={className} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
)

const Content = ({ content, className }) => (
  <div className={className}>{content}</div>
)

Content.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.node,
  className: PropTypes.string,
}

HTMLContent.propTypes = Content.propTypes

export default Content
```

**Called on the page template:**

`<PageContent className="content" content={content} />`

I expect to add an image into the body of markdown, for Gatsby to process the image and output it as a processed/blur up loading image, and for this to work consistently across all servers (localhost and Netlify).

Instead, when it outputs initially (sometimes) it's a huge image, breaking out of containers, then following a server restart or similar the image simply breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a small bug in the version of Netlify CMS I was running - I updated from 2.6.1 to 2.8.0 and this has fixed the issue (as of 2.7.0).